# Jquery ajax post send arabic characters to php and mysql query like

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, utf-8

I have tried many of the solutions found on the net and on StackOverflow, but in my case I was not able to solve the problem.

I want to clarify that all html/php files, the connection to the database and the meta charset are all utf-8 encoded.

I'm sending **post** data through jQuery.ajax() and looking at the source of the post message by firebug, the arabic string is sent like below using only jQuery.serialize() (or serializeArray())

> hp-search=%D9%85%D9%84%D8%AD

In the php file i have a simple query like, and before pass the parameter to the db i'm using urldecode($search_text) (rawurldecode).

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM $db_table
        WHERE $cur_match LIKE '%".urldecode($search_text)."%'";
```

(I know that there is no security in this code, but now I just have to do some testing.)

Trying the query in phpmyadmin, everything works fine, but if i concat the **$sql** string to the ajax response i can see the correct query

```
SELECT * FROM testdb WHERE t_ar LIKE '%ملح%'
```

I've tried several methods but failed to reach a solution.

The jquery script and php works fine with english characters etc.

**I need help :(**

This is the ajax call code

```
........

var serializedDataHP = $("#"+cur_form).serializeArray();

$.mobile.loading("show");

$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    //contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    url: "includes/custom.php?action=search",
    data: serializedDataHP,
    success: function(msg) {
        ........
    },
    error: function() {
        ........
    }
}); ........
```

Thank you

**EDIT**

jQuery used: jquery-1.7.2.min.js (are there bugs related with this version?)

```
var serializedDataHP = $("#"+cur_form).serialize();
```

**PHP**

```
urldecode($search_text)
```

Showing the sql code in ajax response i can see that is correct like i wrote above, but it returns 0 row, in phpmyadmin i obtain 5 results.
What is the correct method to send arabic and non characters through ajax to php all utf8?
Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and the problem was that the hoster had not communicated me the MySQL server upgrade.
So basically I was connecting to the db using these queries

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",$dbhandle);

mysql_query("SET CHARSET 'utf8'",$dbhandle);
```

then using this function instead of the previous

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8", $dbhandle);
```

I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have to unify the character encoding in the html page:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

also try to use json_decode() function

Comment: QUOTE:"I want to clarify that all html/php files, the connection to the database and the meta charset are all utf-8 encoded." I have used <meta charset="utf-8" />